# In the triangle ABC, what's the measure $\angle ACB$?.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: (exact copy of the question) The $\angle B$ of a triangle $ABC$ measures $\angle 16$.
$"I"$ is incenter and $"E"$ is excenter relative to $BC$. If $IE = 2 AC$ , calculate $\angle ACB$.

[image]

My progress: Tried to use similarity of triangles as in another similar question but it still lacks some relationship. Here is the drawing with the relationships I found
[image]

$\angle C = 164^o - \angle A\\
BICE~ is~ cyclic\\
\triangle ACE \sim \triangle AIB \implies \frac{x}{AI}=\frac{CE}{BI}=\frac{AE}{AB}\\
\triangle AIC \sim \triangle ABE \implies \frac{x}{2x+AI}=\frac{CI}{EB}=\frac{AI}{AB}$

Comment: Why don't you type $\angle ACB$ in the title? :)

Comment: @ACB...I've already changed...thanks for alert

Comment: @petaarantes please observe who the comment came from and the relation to $ACB$ :)

Comment: @ACB  ...I'm not serious :(...on the contrary I am extremely calmI just hadn't noticed the symbol :)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Observe,
$$\angle ICE=\angle IBE=90^{\circ}\implies BECI \;\text{is cyclic}. $$
Let $M$ be the midpoint of $IE$ and the center of the circumcircle of quadrilateral $BECI$. We have,
$$ IM=EM=CM=AC.$$
Hence,
$$\angle CAM=\angle CMI=2\angle CBI=16^{\circ}$$
Therefore, $$\angle ACB=180^{\circ}-\angle A-\angle B= 180^{\circ}-32^{\circ}-16^{\circ}=\boxed{132^{\circ}}$$

Comment: @SathvikAcharya you should add a diagram for clarity.

Comment: @ACB  $\triangle ACM$ is isosceles as $AC = CM = IE/2$. Since $\angle AMC = 16^\circ$, $\angle A = 32^\circ$ and it follows that $\angle C = 132^\circ$

Comment: @MathLover I have added a diagram. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: very good Sathvik..thankful for the resolution